# Python built-in sum for nested list

Tags: python, list, sum, nested-lists, built-in

When I finished leetcode 1313, I find a special usage of built-in `sum` function.

### The Leetcode Problem 1313

We are given a list `nums` of integers representing a list compressed with run-length encoding.

Consider each adjacent pair of elements `[a, b] = [nums[2*i], nums[2*i+1]] (with i >= 0)`.  For each such pair, there are `a` elements with value `b` in the decompressed list.

Return the decompressed list.

Example 1:

> ```
> Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
> Output: [2,4,4,4]
> Explanation: The first pair [1,2] means we have freq = 1 and val = 2 so we generate the array [2].
> The second pair [3,4] means we have freq = 3 and val = 4 so we generate [4,4,4].
> At the end the concatenation [2] + [4,4,4,4] is [2,4,4,4].
> ```

### There is a solution using `sum`

```
nums = [1,2,3,4]
g = ([b] * a for a, b in zip(nums[::2], nums[1::2]))
print(list(g))
g = ([b] * a for a, b in zip(nums[::2], nums[1::2]))
print(sum(g,[]))
```

Output:

> ```
> [[2], [4, 4, 4]]
> [2, 4, 4, 4]
> ```

### My question

I can't tell why `sum` can deal with a nested list in this situation. Can any one tell me about it? Or some other functions behavior like this?

Here is the [official guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) for built-in `sum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short-answer

The given code-fragment runs successive list concatenations.

### How it works

Roughly the built-in [*sum()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function works like this:

```
def sum(iterable, /, start=0):
    total = start
    for x in iterable:
        total = total + x
    return total
```

The `+` operator calls `__add__` on the left-hand operand so that `3 + 4` runs as `(3).__add__(4)`, an addition operation on integers.  Likewise, `[10, 20] + [30, 40, 50]` runs as `[10, 20].__add__([30, 40, 50])`, a concatenation operation on lists.

Here's how it plays out in the given example:

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4]
>>> g = ([b] * a for a, b in zip(nums[::2], nums[1::2]))
>>> result = []
>>> x = next(g)
>>> result = result + x
>>> result
[2]
>>> x = next(g)
>>> result = result + x
>>> result
[2, 4, 4, 4]
```

### Why it is not a good idea

Successive list concatenations make next list after each addition, so they run at [`O(n**2)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) speed, meaning that this a quadratic algorithm that runs excessively slow when given large inputs.

### Better way

Instead of building new lists at each step, just [extend](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) the base list in-place.  This runs at [`O(n)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) linear speed:

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4]
>>> g = ([b] * a for a, b in zip(nums[::2], nums[1::2]))
>>> result = []                 # new list
>>> for x in g:
        result.extend(x)        # extend in-place

>>> result
[2, 4, 4, 4]
```

### Even better way

The [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) provides [a tool for chaining together iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).  This makes short-work of the problem:

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4]
>>> g = ([b] * a for a, b in zip(nums[::2], nums[1::2]))
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(g))
[2, 4, 4, 4]
```

This solution is short, fast and works well even with large inputs.

Answer (score 3):

`sum(foo)` simply uses the definition of `+` for the initial value. By default, the initial value is `0`, so `sum(g)` would fail for a list since addition of lists and ints isn't defined. By passing an explicit initial value of `[]`, this forces `sum(foo, [])` to be equal to `foo[0] + foo[1] + ... + foo[n-1] + []`, as observed.

```
>>> sum([[1], [2]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
>>> sum([[1], [2]], [])
[1, 2]
```

The exception to this definition is that you cannot use `sum` with a list of `str` values, even if you specify `""` as the initial value. This is a hard-coded exception, resulting in a `TypeError` with a suggestion to use `str.join` instead.

```
>>> sum(["foo", "bar"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>> sum(["foo", "bar"], "")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]
```